# Not having access to sites and onedrive via ROPC in MS Graph API

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

I used following code to get the MS Graph API access token:

```
# Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)
def ropc_flow_session(AUTHORITY, RESOURCE, username, password, CLIENT_ID):
  context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY)
  token_response = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE, username, password, CLIENT_ID)

  session = requests.Session()
  session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {token_response["accessToken"]}'})
  
  return session
```

The `RESOURCE` and `AUTHORITY` values are:

```
RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
AUTHORITY = F"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"
```

When I call the `ropc_flow_session` function it returns the session that contains following header:

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE}'}
```

So my understanding is I have access to the registered app.
When I try to call `me` with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` the error message says:l

```
 {'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
            'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
```

I tried to have access to a shared library that the user is the owner via  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{TENANT}:/sites/{SITE_NAME}:/drives` and it raised:

```
 {'error': {'code': 'accessDenied',
            'message': 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.',
```

This is the list of registered App API permissions:

[image: permission list]

Based on the error messages it seems like I have connected as an application but I used ROPC and passed a specific user's username and password.
Any thought is appreciated

[UPDATE]
This is the decoded token that I got from jwt.ms:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the access token in https://jwt.ms?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I will update the question with the result of jwt now

Comment: Try getting the accessToken using the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and see if it works.

Comment: How can I use the scope in `acquire_token_with_username_password` function? There is no`scope` parameters for this function. I could update the session to add the scope after having the accessToken but I think you want me to have the scope in the request that I'm  asking for the accessToken not later.

Comment: I could say I used `RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'` when calling the function which I reckon has the same meaning as having `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as `scope` (MS Docs here=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope). please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Just give a try granting admin consent to all the permissions and see it it works. The weird thing is the permissions that you set are not showing up in your token.

Comment: I see your point. Do you mean the delegated permissions on the screenshot? those permissions do not require admin consent

Comment: Yes, just to make sure to get all the permissions in your token. Not sure on python but there is a scope parameter which can get all the permissions. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request). Try to see if you can send it as a parameter with `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` value.

Comment: It seems your decoded access token doesn't contain the permissions. Please have try to do "Grant admin consend for xxx" and then use access token to request graph api.

Comment: Based on the @ShivaKeshavVarma advice I think I see what is the issue here. I had added the delegated API permissions with my own account and now I'm trying to call the API with a service account. The service account is the Azure registered app owner but its account is not on the list of granted consent users in the 'Enterprise applications' link.

Comment: @Amir Maleki, if you add permissions with your service account you would be able to get the results:)-

Comment: Agree, I don't have access to the Azure app registration service with the service account yet. I have requested that from my admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already mentioned in the comments but to make it clear for others that have the same issue I bring more description here.
In my case, the problem was the registered Azure app has two owners. One is my own work account and another is the service account. I added the delegated permissions with my work account and it was showing on the API permissions list. But when I checked the `Enterprise applications` link, it was showing that all the user consent permissions are limited to only 1 specific user

[image: enterprise application]

You could check that by clicking on `Enterprise applications` and see the `user consent` tab

[image: user consent tab]

It has two solutions to resolve the issue:

1. Ask the admin to grant admin consent for the other user as well (in my case it was a service account)
2. Login with the other user (in my case the service account) and add the same API permissions
   I hope this could help others with the same issue

Thanks [@shiva-keshav-varma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12981120/shiva-keshav-varma) for the helpful advice on the comments